# print Array name withing Array ForEach Loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array `$mydata` which looks like the following if i `var_dump($mydata);` I get the following output:

```
array (size=123)
    'PRO01' =>
      array (size=3)
        0 => string 'Category 1'
        1 => string 'Category 2'
        2 => string 'Category 3'
    'PRO02' =>
      array (size=3)
        0 => string 'Another Category 1'
        1 => string 'Another Category 2'
        2 => string 'Another Category 3'
    'PRO03' =>
      array (size=3)
        0 => string '3rd Category 1'
        1 => string '3rd Category 2'
        2 => string '3rd Category 3'
```

Then I have a loop like the following:

```
foreach($mydata as $some){
  var_dump($some);
}
```

Now from this var_dump I can access the nodes of the array. For instance  for the 1st example `PRO01` I could access `Category 1` `Category 2` & `Category 3` as printable output.

Now my question is, within that loop how would I output `PRO01` ie the name of that array?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Thanks for all answers! I knew it was simple. Unfortunately I can't mark them all as correct! Have voted them all up though!

Answer (score 3):

You can get key of the array like this

```
foreach($mydata as $key=>$some){
echo $key;
  var_dump($some);
}
```

where `$key` refers to key of the array item, which you was mentioning as `name`

Answer (score 1):

`foreach($mydata as $key => $value) {}`

You'll now have access to the key, `PR001` and its value, the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     echo $key ; var_dump($value);
}
```